# Ставится ли знак препинания после местоимения перед причастным оборотом?

Tags: пунктуация

**Ты летящий вдаль беспечный ангел.**

Выделяется ли тут оборот (тире, запятая), или знаки не нужны?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант с запятой возможен, если по замыслу автора "ты" выступает в качестве обращения.

В противном случае есть две возможности: никаких знаков препинания (нейтральный вариант) и тире после "ты" (интонационное тире).

Но все это никак не связано с наличием причастного оборота. Те же рассуждения применимы, например, к предложению "Ты беспечный ангел."

Дополнение.

По [Розенталю](http://rosental-book.ru/punct_xxi.html#sect79), тире между подлежащим и сказуемым обычно не ставится, если подлежащее выражено личным местоимением, а сказуемое – именительным падежом существительного, например: …Я честный человек и никогда не говорю комплиментов (Чехов); Я ужасно рада, что ты мой брат (Л. Толстой); Он порча, он чума, он язва здешних мест (Крылов). 
Тире в этом случае ставится при противопоставлении или при логическом подчеркивании сказуемого, например: Ты – старый ребёнок, теоретик, а я – молодой старик и практик… (Чехов); Я – фабрикант, ты – судовладелец… (Горький); Не я, не я, а ты – вредоносный элемент (Федин).

Примечание.

Это слова из песни "Беспечный ангел" группы Ария. В Интернете есть несколько вариантов текста этой песни. На официальном [сайте](http://www.aria.ru/publications/albums/lyrics/bespechnyj.html) группы после "ты" стоит тире: **"Ты - летящий вдаль беспечный ангел"**

Answer (score 3):

Ты **летящий вдаль беспечный** ангел. Но: Ты **беспечный, летящий вдаль**  ангел.

[§ 38. Знаки препинания при однородных определениях](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=114#pp114)

Если причастный оборот стоит **после** определения-прилагательного и перед определяемым словом , **то между определениями ставится запятая:** Даже **старые, серыми лишаями покрытые** ветви деревьев зашептали о прошлых днях.

Если причастный оборот стоит **перед** определением-прилагательным и относится к следующему затем сочетанию определения-прилагательного и определяемого слова, **то запятая между ними не ставится:** Каждый раз появлялась и снова тонула в кромешном мраке **припавшая к широким балкам степная** станица (Пауст.).

Answer (score 1):

Нет, никаких знаков препинания не требуется. В данном случае причастный оборот не обособляется, так как зависимое слово стоит после него.